# Can you configure a Snowflake Security Integration with Tableau to only allow specific roles?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking at these [examples](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-partner.html#examples) in the Snowflake documentation for creating OAuth integration with Tableau. I have noticed that there is a parameter called `BLOCKED_ROLES_LIST` which allows you to list specific roles which should not be able to use the integration.

Is there an equivalent parameter that I can use to list the allowed roles instead? Hypothetically, if we have 100 roles and only want to allow this integration for 1 of them, it seems overly cumbersome to have to list all 99 that we want to block, instead of the 1 to allow?

I have looked through the parameters in the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-security-integration.html#snowflake-oauth) and cannot see a parameter to support this. There is a parameter called `PRE_AUTHORIZED_ROLES_LIST` however this is only supported for confidential clients only and appears to skip the authorisation entirely.

Can you configure a Snowflake Security Integration with Tableau to only allow specific roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an easy way to accomplish this.

The best I can recommend in the meantime is setting up an audit process that could constantly monitor the usage of the Tableau integration in Snowflake - and then trigger the automatic revoking of the privilege.

The basic element in this process is the ability to list the delegated authorizations:

```sql
SHOW DELEGATED AUTHORIZATION
TO SECURITY INTEGRATION td_oauth_int1;
```

[image]

Then to immediately revoke access (unless from the one role allowed):

```sql
ALTER USER fhoffa REMOVE DELEGATED AUTHORIZATION
OF ROLE sysadmin
FROM SECURITY INTEGRATION td_oauth_int1;
```

Comment: That makes sense, though I think it's more cumbersome than needed. For now, I'll create a stored procedure that retrieves all roles and recreates the integration with all of them added to the blocked list. I can then schedule that to run with a task each morning. Thank you though

Comment: Yeah, that stored procedure should work too. Still, plan to audit the `DELEGATED AUTHORIZATION` results - if it's really important to verify that none other than the indicated role has logged in. Also - if my answer was valuable, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.